# jQuery 1.7 on() and off() methods for dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.7

jQuery 1.7's `.on()` and `.off()` methods are supposed to replace `.live()` and such.

I tried it with a dynamic item:

```
 $(".myList").on('click', function(e){
  alert('hello world');
 });
```

This is not working for me for elements added after DOM is loaded.

Is code above a valid example for jQuery 1.7's `.on()` and `.off()` methods?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/ for live() -> on/off() (and other) examples.

This is their example for converting live to on:

```
$('a').live('click', fn);
$(document).on('click', 'a', fn);
```

So your example becomes to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myList', function(e){
  alert('hello world');
});
```

Comment: Something to realize though. on() does not work with dynamically created elements that are appended to the body AND have have a negative z-index. For whatever reason, the click never traverses past the body containing element. The body tag will keep catching all clicks. Even if you make the body a z-index lower than the element being added to the DOM. HOWEVER live() DOES have the power to target these negatively indexed items even though on() cannot.

Comment: @Alex why would you need to dynamically create elements with negative z-index ?

Comment: and most importantly as of jQuery version 1.9.0 - live() method is no longer available.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little example:

http://jsfiddle.net/zzSjK/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(document).on('click','.clickme' , function(e){
          addtext()
        });
        function addtext() {
            $('.myList').append('<div class="clickme">click me</div>')
        }
    })
</script>

<div class="myList">
    <div class="clickme">-click-</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

"Bind" with:

```
$(document).on('click','.myDiv',function(){ ... });
```

And "unbind" with:

```
$(document).off('click','.myDiv');
```