# Newly appended div doesn't inherit event handler in document ready

Tags: jquery

If I append new div on the run, the newly created div doesn't get connected with event handler in document ready.

for example, http://jsfiddle.net/nFG24/

how to assign new div to current event handler in document ready?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery 1.7 on() and off() methods for dynamic elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029589/jquery-1-7-on-and-off-methods-for-dynamic-elements). You need to use `on()` (previously `live()` or `delegate()`) to handle events triggered on dynamic elements.

Comment: have to use on (1.7) or live events

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shortcut event handlers (such as `click()`, `mouseover()` etc) will only apply to elements which are available to the DOM on page load. When appending elements dynamically you have to attach the event to a static parent element, and supply a filter which you wish to delegate events to, like this:

```
$("body").on('mouseover', '.hoverme', function() {
    $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#000'});                    
});
$("body").on('mouseout', '.hoverme', function() {
    $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#0af'});                 
});
```

Note that I've used `body` here as the primary selector. Ideally you should use the closest containing element to the `.hoverme` elements which is not dynamically appended to the DOM.

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nFG24/2/)

Also, you can slightly tidy your code by using `hover()`:

```
$("body").on('hover', '.hoverme', function(e) {
    if (e.type === 'mouseenter')
        $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#000'}); 
    else
        $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#0af'});          
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nFG24/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using .on() yet ? or .bind() in older versions of jQuery 1.7- ?

**.on()**

> **Description:** Attach an event handler function for one or more events
>   to the selected elements.
>   http://api.jquery.com/on/

**.bind()**

> **Description:** Attach a handler to an event for the elements.
>
> http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 0):

Or use live(). This is available for jquery 1.4+, it's deprecated in 1.7 but still works

```
$(".hoverme").live('mouseover', function()
{
    $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#000'});                    
});
$(".hoverme").live('mouseout', function()
{
    $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#0af'});                   
});
```

Comment: thx. it works too, but is there any drawback by using deprecated event handler?

Comment: Yes - if you upgrade to a newer version of jQuery in future it may not work. `delegate()` is a better alternative to `live()`, although that too has now been superceded by `on()` in jQuery 1.7.

Comment: this is good to use if you use some sort of CMS platform where you can't just upgrade the jquery without breaking other functionality and you have to stick with older jquery versions