# jquery .on() does not bind a custom event when injected with .load()

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have those divs with some code in the same document:

```
<div id="trigger">Click Me!</div>
<div id="handler">Handler</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#handler").on('check', function() {alert('Handler is working!');})
    $("#trigger").on('click', function()
       {$("#handler").trigger('check');alert('Trigger is working!')
    })
</script>
```

It's working as expected.

However, if I use `.load()` to inject *all* this into a page, then only the (native) trigger event, not the (custom) handler event is working.

I guess it has something to do with timing but I thought `.on()` was supposed to take care of timing issues?

EDIT: THE SOLUTION

---

I got it all wrong. I wasn't aware that a document loaded simultaneously with the above had its own reference to the Jquery source. So a different version of Jquery was loaded on top of the one already in the DOM. Now it's working without `.ready()` and even with the original syntax.
Thanx!

Comment: If you load everything into the page, the script as well as the elements you bind to, then it might even be enough to wrap your code into a `$(document).ready(function(){//your code here});` which will wait with the execution until the DOM is ready. Otherwise, if you only inject the HTML but not the script then you need to use the `on()` overload for dynamic bindings alright as mentioned by `Mash`.

Comment: I tried that and found with the help of alert() that when injecting with .load() the code ran in exactly the same order as injected, no mather if I put it in $(document).ready(), $(window).ready() or outside any of those functions.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is access the element `#handler` before it exists (.load takes some time to pull it into the page).

Instead, .on also supports the ability to listen on elements that don't yet exist.

```
$("body").on("click", "#handler", function() { alert("Clicked on #handler"); });
```

This will listen on the body element (which should exist) for any click on an element with ID #handler, even if it is later injected.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that .on() differs in functionality depending on syntax. Unfortunately my example code was too much simplified. In my real code I simultaneously load two other (unrelated) divs with $.post. I've now found that if I comment out those two calls it works fine, with both syntaxes. If I let the calls run, only the native click event will work.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to specify the parent selector to taking into account the elements created dynamicaly.

Exemple :

```
$("body").on('check', '#handler', function() {alert('Handler is working!');})
```

Here is a good related question : [jQuery 1.7 on() and off() methods for dynamic elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029589/jquery-1-7-on-and-off-methods-for-dynamic-elements)