# javaScript not working for page loaded by jquery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Page 1**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head></head>
<body><div id="main"></div> </body>
<script>$('div[id=main]').load('page2.php')
$('span[id*=temp]').on('click',function(){
alert(this.id); }); //this block of code not working!!
</script>
</html>
```

**Page 2**

```
<div>
<span id="temp">
this is demo
</span>
</div>
```

Basically i want to load page2 again in main div when  tag is clicked but am not able to fetch the id of the  tag in page one,script of page1 not working for page 2 items or tags

Comment: Your span doesn't exist when the code that binds the event runs. http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: pls give a solution @KevinB

Comment: there's a solution at the link i provided and on the documentation page for `.on()`, i don't need to create a third. http://api.jquery.com/on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to bind the event right after the AJAX call, so the element doesn't exist yet. The call is asynchronous, so it doesn't stop the code execution to wait for the response.

Either bind the element after the content has loaded, using the `success` callback of the `load` method:

```
$('div#main').load('page2.php', function(){
  $('span[id*=temp]').on('click', function(){
    alert(this.id);
  });
});
```

or use a delegate to bind the event to the parent element:

```
$('div#main').load('page2.php');
$('div#main').on('click', 'span[id*=temp]', function(){
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to specify the parent selector to taking into account the elements created dynamicaly.

Exemple :

```
$("#main").on('click', 'span[id*="temp"]', function() {alert('Handler is working!');})
```

Here is a good related question : [jQuery 1.7 on() and off() methods for dynamic elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029589/jquery-1-7-on-and-off-methods-for-dynamic-elements)

Comment: You have a syntax error. Change 'span[id*=temp]' by 'span[id*="temp"]', I have updated my answer

Comment: The inner quotes are not required.

Comment: inverted comma ie " " are included when name has number or _ otherwise we don't need them