# jQuery .on not working correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I'm playing around with pagination and jQuery, my code first looked like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".pagination a").live("click", function() {
        $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Then I noticed that `live` was removed in jQuery 1.9 so I changed my code to:

```
$(function() {
    $(".pagination").on("click", 'a', function() {
        $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
        return false;
    });
});
```

But somehow this also won't work! The problem is that I can navigate from the first ajax page to the second but then form the second back to the first page or to the third page my ajax is not working. I supose because my code does not regognice the new added `.pagination a`.

Comment: replace `.pagination` with a static container, for better performance, chose the closest to `.pagination a`.

Comment: Are you replacing the original `.pagination` element? If so, you should  apply the `.on` method to some high-level wrapper

Comment: +1 @gdoron for the best answer in a comment.

Comment: This answer might help you. You're trying to attach click event listeners to dynamically created elements (which I overlooked when first answering). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029589/jquery-1-7-on-and-off-methods-for-dynamic-elements

Comment: @technophobia, thanks, I was upset with all the answers, so finally I wrote an answer explaining why they were all wrong.(I tried to be as polite as possible while being angry... `:)` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `on` is bound only for existing elements, if you want to make it listen to elements that  were inserted after you use `on` you have to add a selector argument.
  With a selector argument it's a delegate event, while without it's a direct event.
- If you used `on` delegate event signature the callback is bound to the selector which the `on` was called upon `$('thisSelector')`, while it will listen to the events of the elements in the selector argument like
  `$('foo').on('event', 'thisSelector', func)`.
- For better performance you should attach the `on` function to the closest static element to the newly inserted elements, this is actually the main reason why `live` was removed from jQuery in version 1.9, `live` attaches the listener to the `document` which has enormous performance penalty.

What we learned from the above, you must make sure `.pagination` is already in the DOM when you call `on`, and it shouldn't be replaced.

Now you should come with something like:

```
$("{staticElement-closeToTheNewElements}").on("click", '.pagination a',callback);
```

Comment: I didn't know `.live` worked by attaching to `document`. Thanks!

Comment: @Jayraj, And I'm sorry for being rude, it is that 6 wrong answers can make you angry... I didn't want to answer it and left a comment, just when wrong answers got upvoted I answered. Again sorry for being rude.

Comment: Lol. I would see 6 wrong answers as an opportunity, personally :P. And I'm happy to have learned something new today, so no worries.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".pagination a", function () {
        $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: one of the reasons `live` is dead is so you won't bind the callbacks to the `document`.

Answer (score 1):

If you call:

<s>$(document).on("click", '.pagination a', function(){...})</s>

Should be:

```
$('#container-element').on("click", '.pagination a', function(){...})
```

it will [call the event on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) any dynamically created element that matches the selector.

See [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18856714/1149459) for optimal answer.

Comment: @user2724695, please don't use it. it's not personal, but this answer isn't optimal, far from that. And if the event was `onmousemove` or similar mouse events you would event notice that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping your html would like similar to this: If your div with class pagination is loaded via ajax it won't help by using it for event delegation since its not static.

```
 <body>
    <div id="static_div">
      <div class="pagination">
        <a href="" id="alink">I'm a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Use

```
$('#static_div').on('click', '.pagination a', function(){...});
```

I'd suggest not to use `body` or `document` & use the closest static container to pagination for performance gain.